# openmp core assignation fails

Tags: linux, openmp, icc

My Centos 6 VM shows four cores when displaying the content of `/proc/cpuinfo`, and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/online` shows `0-3`.

I am trying to run the following code on the core 2 and 3 using `KMP_AFFINITY="explicit,proclist=[2-3]"`

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
int nthreads, tid, cid;

    #pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, tid)
    {
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        cid = sched_getcpu();
        printf("Hello from thread %d on core %d\n", tid, cid);

        if (tid == 0) {
            nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
            printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
        }
    }
}
```

When compiled with `icc (ICC) 16.0.1 20151021`, it it fails to detect the available cores and executes everything on the core 0.

```
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./a.out 
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 2.
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 3.
OMP: Warning #124: No valid OS proc IDs specified - not using affinity.
Hello from thread 0 on core 0
Number of threads = 1
Hello from thread 0 on core 0
Number of threads = 1
Hello from thread 0 on core 0
Number of threads = 1
Hello from thread 0 on core 0
Number of threads = 1
```

Where as `gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313`, with `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="2-3"`, executes properly on core 2 and 3, like set.

I used `strace` to check what's going on under the hood, and I noticed something strange :

```
[...]
open("/sys/devices/system/cpu/online", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "0-3\n", 8192)                  = 4
[...]
sched_getaffinity(0, 1048576,  { 1 })   = 8
sched_setaffinity(0, 8,  { 4521c26fbb1c38c1 }) = -1 EFAULT (Bad addres
[...]
```

Could this be an error from the implementation of OpenMP made by intel?

I cannot upgrade my compiler to fix it in this case. Is it possible to use the GCC OpenMP library instead of the Intel one when compiling with `icc` ?

Update:

I managed to compile the code with `gcc` and linking it with `iomp` using the following command
`gcc omp.c -L/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016/linux/lib/intel64_lin/ -liomp5`

The execution outputs no warning, and is still not correct:

```
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./a.out 
Hello from thread 0 on core 0
Number of threads = 1
```

Same `sched_setaffinity` error than previously shown.

Comment: Did you enable OpenMP support for icc? This was done I believe in this version with flag `-fopenmp` but maybe it was already `-qopenmp`. Idem when compiling with gcc, you need the `-fopenmp` switch. Finally, your `cid` variable needs to be declared `private` as well.

Comment: @Gilles yes OpenMP is enabled, it works fine on any other configurations. What do you mean by `private` ? Proper to the thread ?